# ASP.NET Identity - can't register UserTokenProvider

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an issue with generating the reset password token in the ASP.NET Core 1.0 project:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddIdentity<UserDB, GroupDB>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
}
```

then in my controller with DI:

```
...
UserManager<UserDB> userManager
...


string token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

and I get

> **No IUserTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered.**

How to fix it ?

I can see there's no Providers inside of my `UserStore` constructor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `UserStore` class didn't have the `IUserTokenProvider` interface implementation. Also, in the `ApplicationUserManager` class constructor, I check if the `TokenProviderDescriptor` is registered

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<UserDB>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(UserStore store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<UserDB> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<UserDB>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<UserDB>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<UserDB>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger, contextAccessor)
    {
        if (!optionsAccessor.Value.Tokens.ProviderMap.ContainsKey("DefaultTokenProvider"))
            optionsAccessor.Value.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("DefaultTokenProvider", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(UserStore)));
    }
}
```

That's solved the issue. Thanks for the help !